# Mysterious, Undesired Outline Around Black Illustrator Shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Why do black shapes end up having a faint outline around them? Will there be any consequences to this when I print? Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YjgKd.png) in the marked duplicate has the same outline if you look closely (it's difficult to see when it's scaled down in the post)